# Gem causes builds to fail. Point to local lib?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems

I am using a gem which was recently updated. The last update is causing my builds to fail (uses uncompiled `SCSS` inside a `.css` file). I fixed the issue and created a pull request, but the author is not responding to the issue I opened and / or merging my PR.

Would it be a good idea to store the gem locally, push it to my production and staging and point to it from the Gemfile until the issue gets fixed in the main repo?

Comment: I think, you could refer latest branch to the gem like, `gem 'gem_name', :github => 'github_repo', :branch => 'branch'`

Comment: thought of that. The gem's repo only has one branch - `master`.  I ended up pointing the gem source to the local repo I created for the Pull Request.